# What is the best way to achieve visual list of items in Cocoa/Objective-C (like Things)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I am wanting to create a list of items in with Objective-C like the list of tasks in Things... like this:

https://skitch.com/mattfordham/r4t5a/things

Each item could have buttons associated with it, text, whatever. NSTableView was my first thought, but seems I can customize it as much as I am needing. Perhaps each row would be a custom NSView and I manage the positioning of each item in the list manually? Thanks for any help.

Comment: It’s hard to answer this question without knowing your actual requirements. What makes you think you cannot do what you want with `NSTableView`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `NSTableView` and `NSCollectionView` allow custom cells/views — in fact, they’re required for the latter. I’d personally use `NSTableView` for something similar to what you’ve depicted.

You could also use third party classes like [PXListView](http://perspx.com/work/), whose source code is open and licenced under the new BSD licence. Or, as mentioned by David Barry, the [Chameleon Project](http://chameleonproject.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the *best*  way, but one possibility may be using the [Chameleon Project](http://chameleonproject.org/) which is basically UIKit for OS X.  This would allow you to use a UITableview, which uses a UIView to display each row.  This should make it much easier for you to customize your rows to your hearts content.

It may be overkill adding the full Chameleon Framework if you'll one be using it for the one interface element(and have no plans of sharing code between OS X and iOS), and if you don't have any experience with UIKit already that will add to the learning curve.